# SQL Query guaranteed to return Empty

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm fairly new to SQL. I'm trying to create a JTable that initially does not show any results, but will show them after I execute certain SQL queries. How do I achieve this? Is there some way I can write a query that is guaranteed to return empty?

I've tried

```
SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE false
```

But that gives me a result set with one column - I want a resultset that has the same number of columns as in my underlying table, but with no rows.

Comment: MySQL does not have a DUAL table. Which Database are you really using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting your columns from the table, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> LIMIT 0
```

where table_name is the name of your table from where you're trying to fetch the columns. This query signifies that you're trying to fetch all the columns from the table while trying to limit the rows to 0

Comment: @praks5432 - it worked because * means you're trying to fetch all the columns in your table, and limit 0 signifies that you're trying to fetch a total of 0 rows